# Read only file in Zip archive

Tags: java, zip

I'm trying to generate a zip file with java.util.zip API and I haven't found any way to set zip entry as read only file. I would like to create a new ZIP archive, put files inside it and set read only flag for all those files that appear inside of the ZIP file (on Windows platform).
I am aware that java.util.zip API works with Streams instead of File objects (File object has method setReadonly()).
I also tried with Apache Commons Compress API and haven't found solution as well. 
Please help!

Comment: How about setting RO permission before compressing it?

Comment: Saravana, it does not work, in ZIP archive all entries skipped this readonly  flag, probably because java.util.zip API works with Stream (ZipOutputStream ) object.

Comment: If you're on Unix environment write a ProcessBuilder, invoke systems commands to set RO permission and compress, but it'll become platform dependent.