# How to make files that get zipped read only

Tags: java

I have a list of files that I need to zip and I am using ZipOutputStream.

When I get the files I set each to read only. (I have tried with file.setWritable(false) and file.setReadOnly())

The original file gets changed but the one that get saved inside the zip is not ready only. I'm guessing this is because I have to use FileInputStream to add each file into the zip.

For testing I am using example code I found online.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class TestZip {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try {

            File zipFile = new File("C:\\Users\\thop\\Desktop\\Test\\test.txt");
            zipFile.setWritable(false);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\thop\\Desktop\\Test\\MyFile.zip");
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(zipFile.getAbsolutePath());
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(zipFile.getAbsolutePath());
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            zos.closeEntry();
            zos.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Is there a way to make the file that gets zipped read only?

Example: 
The file I am saving gets set to read only. 
[image: File that gets zipped]

When I save the test.txt in a zip file and extract it in the MyFile folder it isn't read only anymore. 
[image: Explanation]

Comment: What do you mean with read-only here? The user should not be allowed to change the zip itself? The user should not be allowed to change the contents of the extracted file? Btw, your 3rd paragraph is hard to understand due to missing punctuation. Please edit that to help us understand what you're after - and while you're at it you could add the answers to my questions to your post and maybe add some example.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry if I was unclear. I have added an image as an example. When I run the code I have provided above the test.txt gets zipped. After I unzip the file in MyFile.zip the unzipped file does not have the Read-only attribute  set as true.

Comment: This question is similar to mine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188981/read-only-file-in-zip-archive
But there is also no solution for it.

Comment: Well, AFAIK Java's built-in zip functionality doesn't support everything, e.g. it at least used to not support password encryption. You could try with Apache Commons Compress though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZipOutputStream doesn't use the files that are saved but it reads them and then zips them.

If you want to use the files you have access to and to keep them the same as they are you can use [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/)